# AWS Cost Explorer: Lambda error : getCostForecast is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to get costForecast for my account using javascript sdk in lambda but I always get the error- 'TypeError: .... getCostForecast is not a function ' in cloudwatch logs. I am able to call the api CostExplorer.getCostForecast() using AWS CLI as well as in samLocal. For working in samlocal, initially I got the same error but after upgrading aws-sdk to 2.449.0 it worked. For dev setup I am deploying through cloudformation where we never send aws-sdk package since lambda takes care of it.

[CostExplorer.html#getCostForecast-property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CostExplorer.html#getCostForecast-property)

I read that getCostForecast is available in javascript apiVersion:2017-10-25 and I tried after defining it but still same error.I also tried using 'latest' in apiVersion as suggested in docs for latest sdk but still unable to fix it. Please help !I am using nodejs8.10.

**Code Snippets**

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you share your code snippet ?

Comment: I have added it.. please have a check.

Answer (score 1):

The method `getCostForecast` has been added to the `aws-sdk-js` in version [2.358.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/3a8901f1c92e417562b27d5541b8bcd6ca37c31c/.changes/2.358.0.json).

Unfortunately, the current version of the `aws-sdk-js` running in Lambda is 2.290.0. You can check this with `console.log(AWS.VERSION)` in your function. This is also described in [AWS Lambda Runtimes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html).

If you want to use `getCostForecast` in Lambda you will have to pack a version greater than or equal to 2.358.0 of the `aws-sdk-js` in your function's zip (in order to not rely on the available version in the runtime).

Comment: Yes you are right. Lambda runtime nodejs8.10 runs 2.290 aws-sdk. I will definetly try this out and update the status.. Thanks !